# How does the `q` parameter work with the YouTube API?

Tags: jquery, python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using YouTube's API and I am confused about how the `q` parameter at `youtube.search().list()` works.

In general adding a `q` parameter works as setting the keyword to search. However, not adding this parameter, the API will also retrieve videos.

Where do these videos come from? Are they random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list):

> string
>
> The **q** parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to
>   exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of
>   several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching
>   either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either
>   "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be
>   URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value
>   for the pipe character is %7C.

If you don't add the `q` parameter, videos are still being search based on other parameters you have entered.

Comment: May you include spaces with the **q** parameter value? ie: `cryptocurrency|digital currency|crypto`

Comment: Also, what is the limit for the number of keywords that can be passed in with the `q` parameter?